# Apache Velocity : Verify if all substitutions are made

Tags: velocity

Can someone let me know how I can verify a velocity context against a template? Basically, I want to throw some error if all variables are not substituted in the velocity template.

For example, let's say I have a velocity template, `card.vm`

```
  card {
    type: CREDIT
    company: VISA
    name: "${firstName} ${lastName}"
  }
```

The substitution is done like below

```
VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
velocityEngine.init();
   
Template t = velocityEngine.getTemplate("card.vm");
    
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("firstName", "tuk");
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
t.merge( context, writer );
```

In this case, I want to throw some error specifying that `lastName` is not replaced in template.

Does velocity provide anything for this?

- Velocity Version - 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in [velocity mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread/d481p9w4szgc6oxkql2ykzxf06xmg1kz)

> No, but it would be easy to do. Instead of using the basic
> `VelocityContext`, wrap it in a custom one, something like this:
>
> ```
> public class WarningVelocityContext
>      extends VelocityContext
> {
>      public Object get(String key) {
>          Object o = super.get(key);
>
>          if(null == o) {
>              throw new IllegalStateException("Key {" + key + "} has not
> been set");
>          }
>      }
> }
> ```
>
> Then in your code, wrap the context right before merging:
>
> `t.merge(new WarningVelocityContext(context), writer);`
>
> Note that this will throw exceptions for *anything* that's not found
> for any reason. If you try something like:
>
> `$someObject.method()`
>
> And "someObject" is null, then you'll get an error. It may be
> difficult to tell the difference between the things you "care about"
> and the things you do not. If you have a simple use-case, then
> probably this will work.